# I need to read a text file and insert specific values to csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas, list

The following is the file i want to work on

---

### slot

```
              slot : acu:1/1                         planned-type : ngfc-f                           actual-type : ngfc-f                           oper-status : enabled              
      error-status : no-error                                                                       availability : available            
     alarm-profile : none                                                                          capab-profile : not_applicable       
      manufacturer : ALCL                                                                                                                                                              
          mnemonic : NGFC-F                                                                                                                                                            
          pba-code :                                                                                                                                                                   
         fpba-code : 3FE64993AABA                                                                                                                                                      
          fpba-ics : 01                                                                                                                                                                
         clei-code : VAUCAJ66AA                                                                                                                                                        
         serial-no : 1743A13DC                                                                                                                                                         
       failed-test : 00:00:00:00                                                                                                                                                       
   lt-restart-time : 1970-01-01:05:45:00         lt-restart-cause : timezone_modified             lt-restart-num : 0                         restart-cnt-per-lt : 0
```

### mgnt-entity-oamipaddr : 0.0.0.0                  mgnt-entity-pairnum : 0                               dual-host-ip : 0.0.0.0                        dual-host-loc : none

---

### slot

```
              slot : acu:1/1                         planned-type : ngfc-f                           actual-type : ngfc-f                           oper-status : enabled              
      error-status : no-error                                                                       availability : available            
     alarm-profile : none                                                                          capab-profile : not_applicable       
      manufacturer : ALCL                                                                                                                                                              
          mnemonic : NGFC-F                                                                                                                                                            
          pba-code :                                                                                                                                                                   
         fpba-code : 3FE64993AABA                                                                                                                                                      
          fpba-ics : 01                                                                                                                                                                
         clei-code : VAUCAJ66AA                                                                                                                                                        
         serial-no : 1743A13DC                                                                                                                                                         
       failed-test : 00:00:00:00                                                                                                                                                       
   lt-restart-time : 1970-01-01:05:45:00         lt-restart-cause : timezone_modified             lt-restart-num : 0                         restart-cnt-per-lt : 0
```

### mgnt-entity-oamipaddr : 0.0.0.0                  mgnt-entity-pairnum : 0                               dual-host-ip : 0.0.0.0                        dual-host-loc : none

I want to iterate through the text file and need an output as below in CSV

```
Slot    error-status alarm-profile manufacturer mnemonic
acu:1/1 no-error       none         ALCL          NGFC-F
```

```
fopen=open("gthamelslot.txt")
for lines in fopen:
    a = lines.strip()
    b=a.split()
    print(b[0][0])
```

I am stuck on this. Please help me with a logic with what can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

result = defaultdict(list)

with open('gthamelslot.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = re.search(r"\s+(\S+)\s+:\s+(\S+)", line)
        if match:
            k,v = match.group(1), match.group(2)
            if k in ["slot", "error-status", "alarm-profile", "manufacturer", "mnemonic"]:
                result[k].append(v)

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df)
```

**Update**

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

result = defaultdict(list)

with open('gthamelslot.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = re.findall(r"\s+(\S+)\s+:\s+(\S+)", line)
        for k,v in match:
            if k in ["slot", "error-status", "alarm-profile", "manufacturer", "mnemonic", "planned-type"]:
                result[k].append(v)

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df)
```

Comment: It worked great but the same given texts are repeated multiple times in the text file and it is only looping through the first part. And it is also omitting the "planned-type : ngfc-f " section.

Comment: were you able to fix the problem?

Comment: Yes, but the omition is seen as explained above

Comment: You need to add `planned-type` to the `if` condition

Comment: `if k in ["slot", "error-status", "alarm-profile", "manufacturer", "mnemonic", "planned-type"]:`

Comment: if k in ["slot",
                     "error-status",
                     "alarm-profile",
                     "manufacturer",
                     "mnemonic",
                     "pba-code",
                     "fpba-code",
                     "fpba-ics",
                     "clei-code",
                     "serial-no",
                     "failed-test",
                     "lt-restart-time",
                     "planned-type"]:
                result[k].append(v)  Already did but it is not showing up

Comment: fixed that. it was because `search` only finds the first match. replaced that with `findall`. `planned-type` and `slot` are in the same line and that was the reason it was not working.

Comment: Thank you so much. one last help would be great. The same lists  with titles repeat multiple times. and the loop seems to be running only till the last value of first section. How can i iterate and add the values in the next row with same header

Answer (score 0):

Modify accordingly

```
   import csv
   filepointer = open("file.txt", 'r+')
   file = filepointer.readlines()
   filelinelist = []
   for i in file:
     filelinelist.append(i)
   firstlist = []
   secondlist = []
   for line in filelinelist:
     lineArray = line.split(":")
     first = lineArray[0].strip()
     second = lineArray[1].strip()
     firstlist.append(first)
     secondlist.append(second)
     finalList = []
     finalList.append(firstlist)
     finalList.append(secondlist)

   myFile = open('csvfile.csv', 'w')
   with myFile:
     writer = csv.writer(myFile)
     writer.writerows(finalList)
```